# How to make use of ruby procs to dynamically execute a database query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model called Bucket which has this instance method
`Bucket#populate_students_academicwise(mentor)`

```
def populate_students_academicwise(mentor)
  student_ids = Mark.find(:all,
    :joins => self.student_current_klass,
    :conditions => ["marks.subject_id = ? AND st.klass_id = ? AND marks.klass_id = ? AND u.account_enabled IS TRUE AND sub.active IS TRUE AND k.active IS TRUE", mentor.subject_id, mentor.klass_id, mentor.klass_id],
    :group => "marks.student_id",
    :having => ["ROUND(AVG(marks_obtained)/AVG(marks_total)*100) BETWEEN ?  AND  ?", min_range, max_range]).collect(&:student_id)

  self.assign_students(student_ids)
end
```

Now, this query returns a set of students whose academic performance is between a range of values

```
ROUND(AVG(marks_obtained)/AVG(marks_total)*100) BETWEEN ?  AND  ?)
```

I call this method from a `bucket` instance like this `bucket.populate_students_academicwise(mentor)`

I'd like to negate that query, meaning, return the set of students whose academic performance is NOT between a range of values. All I can think of is to create another method that runs negative of the above query. So I have another method `Bucket#negate_populate_students_academicwise(mentor)`

```
def negate_populate_students_academicwise(mentor)
    Mark.find(:all,
      :joins => self.student_current_klass,
      :conditions => ["marks.subject_id = ? AND st.klass_id = ? AND marks.klass_id = ? AND u.account_enabled IS TRUE AND sub.active IS TRUE AND k.active IS TRUE", mentor.subject_id, mentor.klass_id, mentor.klass_id],
      :group => "marks.student_id",
      :having => ["ROUND(AVG(marks_obtained)/AVG(marks_total)*100) NOT BETWEEN ?  AND  ?", min_range, max_range]).collect(&:student_id)
end
```

Now, this query returns a set of students whose academic performance is NOT between a range of values `ROUND(AVG(marks_obtained)/AVG(marks_total)*100) NOT BETWEEN ?  AND  ?`

How can I call the first method `Bucket#populate_students_academicwise(mentor)` with a negate method appended to it `bucket.populate_students_academicwise(mentor).negate` that would call a proc to negate the query?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to basically have both functionalities and still have them in a DRY way?

I would say you should use a default parameter.

```
bucket.populate_students_academicwise(mentor) # dont negate
bucket.populate_students_academicwise(mentor,false) # negate
```

Within you method

```
def populate_students_academicwise(mentor,in_range = true)
  student_ids = Mark.find(:all,
                   :joins => self.student_current_klass,
                   :conditions => ["marks.subject_id = ? AND st.klass_id = ? AND marks.klass_id = ? AND u.account_enabled IS TRUE AND sub.active IS TRUE AND k.active IS TRUE", mentor.subject_id, mentor.klass_id, mentor.klass_id],
                   :group => "marks.student_id",
                   :having => ["ROUND(AVG(marks_obtained)/AVG(marks_total)*100) #{'NOT' if !in_range} BETWEEN ?  AND  ?", min_range, max_range]).collect(&:student_id)
  self.assign_students(student_ids)
end
```

With that little bit of query manipulation you get your NOT (or no NOT) depending on the parameter and dont need to worry about proc here.

Comment: Thanks. But if there could be a solution like what I wished.`bucket.populate_students_academicwise(mentor).negate` looks nicer than this `bucket.populate_students_academicwise(mentor,false)`. Isn't it?

Comment: @vineeth. Whether it looks nice or not is debatable. :) Ideally you should separate out the concern of finding the student_ids and the assigning of students. You could then build up 3 scopes. the first one is the base scope, the second one with in range having clause the last one with not in range having clause. then stick the relevant having scope to the base scope to get the result you want. You should try writing the above in ActiveRelation (unless you are stuck on Rails 2?). Need help with explaining my solution?

Comment: I agree. Your solution is functionally correct. But my purpose of the question was to find a way to make my method call that would look like this `bucket.populate_students_academicwise(mentor).negate`, that's all :)

Comment: understood. and i'm just suggesting that putting negate at the end of the chain is too late. it's too late because you're doing too much in your populate_students_academicwise method (you're doing 2 things, fetch and assign). if you separated the concern (fetch and assigning) there is "scope" for what you want to achieve.

Comment: Is there a way, though? Can you suggest? I'll try moving the assignment operation to the method that called this. I'm also quite eager to know how I could use of procs, practically, in a rails project.

Comment: By the way @Aditya, thanks for the above answer. Changed the code for now as you suggested :)